# How do I get python to only accept alphabet inputs?

Tags: python

I'm a noob at programming but I wanted the script to only accept alphabet inputs rather than numbers too. Especially only one alphabet. Thanks

```
for x in range (0, 90000):
("Type alphabet") 
cha1=input()
complete = choice(list1)

if (cha1) == (complete):
            print ("Try again")


if (cha1) != (complete):
    print (complete)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response will give you some hints about input validation.

Comment: try using `if  cha1.isalpha()`

Comment: In the future, please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'somestring'.isalpha():
    do_stuff()
```